# Write a test template with multiple keywords

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to write a test template with multiple keywords?
I'm looking for something like:

```
Valid Login
    [Template]
    Given login page is open
    When ${username} and ${password} are inserted
    and user is on ${device}
    Then welcome page should be open
    root  abc  desktop
    noman  xyz  laptop
```

It would be a bonus if I could use a list instead of a data table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way is to create a new keyword that calls those keywords, and set the template in the settings:

```
*** Settings ***

    Test template  Valid Login

*** Test cases ***

    root  abc  desktop
    noman  xyz  laptop

*** Keywords ***

Valid Login
    [Arguments]  ${username}  ${password}  ${device}
    Given login page is open
    When ${username} and ${password} are inserted
    and user is on ${device}
    Then welcome page should be open
```

Comment: I don't particularly like having my BDD cases in Keywords. I was trying to shy the stakeholder away from anything but test cases. But fair enough, I'll accept it.